# Find bounds of $\prod_{i=1}^k (x_i-x_{i+1})$ where $\sum_{i=1}^k x^2_i=1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ be real numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^k x^2_i=1$. Determine the minimum and maximum (if there is) value of $$\prod_{i=1}^k (x_i-x_{i+1})$$ and determine all values of $(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_k)$ such that the minimum value is achieved. ($ k \ge 2$)

This question is a generalized version of the question APMO 2022 P5 ($k=4$), and [regional stage of All-Russian MO 2018, 9.5.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1858702p12564948) ($k=3$).

The problem is, since this is a generalized version, the strategy I did in $k=3,4$ does not work here. In small $k$, it is sufficient to use AM-GM, but since there are more variables in this question, I have no idea how do attack this problem, can someone help me please? I don't need solution, just a hint to solve the generalized version

Comment: Are the indices meant to be read modulo $k$? The last factor in the given expression contains the number $x_{k+1}$, which is not defined in the statement of the problem.

Comment: oh sorry for not mentioning this, yes, it is meant to be read $\mod k$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain your approach to the special cases, or provide links to the solutions of the contest problems you mentioned?

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1858702p12564948 #2 is my exact idea for the case $k=3$, $k=4$ uses the same idea too

Comment: $$\prod_{i=1}^k (x_i-x_{i+1})$$ should be $$(x_1-x_k)\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (x_i-x_{i+1}).$$